# Does Apple Thunderbolt Monitor just not work with Thunderbolt 4 ports (Intel Tiger Lake)

Tags: thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I've had this Apple Thunderbolt monitor since 2012.  It was used with a 2011 Macbook Air and a 2015 Dell m3800 (linux) without issue and the monitor itself still works great.  So far, I cannot get it to "work" (it never shows up in messages or logs, never turns on, its like its not even there) with a new Dell XPS13 9130.

This system has 2 Thunderbolt 4 ports built on Intel Tiger Lake chipset.  Thunderbolt is set in the BIOS to allow everything and initialize everything.  I am trying to connect it using a Thunderbolt 3 to 2 convertor (have tried both Apple and StarTech).  This system is a dual-boot and the same issue happens both in Windows 10 and Linux (Gentoo and Fedora).

I thought I read somewhere that Intel purposefully prevented this monitor from working with Thunderbolt 4 ports; but to be fair I am having trouble finding that information again and it does not really make that much sense.

Does anyone have any insights into the issue here?  Should it work or not?  If anyone has gotten this to work, what was the solution?

Comment: The Apple Thunderbolt Display will certainly work with modern Macs using an adapter. Some aspect of the Dell Windows PC is likely the issue... https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207266

Comment: Just created this account so I can reply - I faced something similar with a Thunderbolt display on a HP 800 G4 SFF (also with Gentoo). Check in your BIOS settings if you have Thunderbolt security settings and set it to none.